# Modify Stack in the Zend HeadScript View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I am trying to attack [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253170/zend-framework-last-code-to-execute-before-layout-is-rendered) from a completely different angle, because it doesn't look like I can achieve my goal that way.

I want to loop over the item stack in the [HeadScript View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript), and make modifications to it.  [The documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript) for this and some of the other view helpers makes this statement:

> HeadScript overrides each of append(),
>   offsetSet(), prepend(), and set() to
>   enforce usage of the special methods
>   as listed above. Internally, it stores
>   each item as a stdClass  token, which
>   it later serializes using the
>   itemToString()  method. This allows
>   you to perform checks on the items in
>   the stack, and optionally modify these
>   items by simply modifying the object
>   returned.

So, where is this "object returned"?  I am missing a piece of the puzzle here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `toString()` method of `Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript` I noticed a `foreach()` loop on `$this`, so I tried that and it worked.  Here's a HeadScript extension I wrote that illustrates the solution:

```
class My_View_Helper_HeadScript extends Zend_View_Helper_HeadScript
{
    public function toString($indent = null)
    {
        $files = array();
        foreach ($this as $key => $item) {
            if (!empty($item->attributes)
                    && array_key_exists('src', $item->attributes)
                    && ('scripts' == substr($item->attributes['src'], 1, 7))) {
                $files[] = $item->attributes['src'];
                unset($this[$key]);
            }
        }
        if (0 < count($files)) {
            $this->prependFile('/combo.php?type=scripts&files=' . implode(',', $files));
        }
        return parent::toString($indent);
    }
}
```

In `Bootstrap.php` the following lines to point to my helpers:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
$view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');
```

In my layout, I have this line:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
```

---

If my solution is unclear in any way, let me know and I'll update it to clarify.

Comment: how do you use it ? i've trying to get this to work http://blog.hines57.com/2011/03/13/zendframework-minify/ by simply having to change one like in the layout echo $this->miniHeadScript()

Comment: @max4ever - I have added more details to the solution. It overloads the existing `$this->headScript()` call.  Changing to `miniHeadScript()` is an additional step.

Comment: i don't know why but the foreach ($this ...) always skips on my configuration, i found the solution to be, to iterate over $this->view->headLink(); i posted some comments on the blog http://blog.hines57.com/2011/03/13/zendframework-minify/comment-page-1/#comment-353

Comment: @max4ever - It's because you changed the name of the view helper

Comment: ehm, sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: I left a comment on your blog.

Comment: it won't work for some reason, nevermind i'll just use my "hack"