# Zend Framework - call something at the end of building a page

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Hi I would like to call a method at the end of a page generation using Zend Framework. How to do this?

I am using Doctrine2 + ZF. The EntityManager has a flush method, which should in the common cases only be called at the end of the page generation. Is there a hook or a destructor emulation in Zend Framework? 2

Comment: Ok recently this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253170/zend-framework-last-code-to-execute-before-layout-is-rendered helped me more than the answers here. I had to overwrite postDispatch() but maybe I am going to change this, to be able to display an error message if an error on $em->flush() occours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [**controller plugin**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html). I assume the dispatchLoopShutdown is what you need.

Comment: Is calling the parent method recommended? 
 protected function dispatchLoopShutdown(){
  parent::dispatchLoopShutdown();
  $this->_em->flush();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't use your own function?

call `register_shutdown_function();` and the passed function will be executed at the end of the script